# Apply gesture effects only when the user touches the object

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, xna-4.0, monogame

I am a newbie in game development, and I am developing a concept for windows store using monogame implementation of XNA where in, I am making a ball move on flick gesture. But, my problem is the ball moves not only on applying the gesture on to the ball but applying the gesture anywhere on the screen makes my ball move. What I want is, my ball shall only move when I apply flick on the ball itself but not on the other areas of the screen. I am using rectangle bounding box to see whether user touches the ball object but in vain.

I am sharing with my method to Update Gametime

```
    //Global vars
    //cat is the ball object here
    GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
    SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;
    private Texture2D cat;
    private Vector2 _spritePosition;
    private SpriteFont _fontMiramonte;
    BounceableImage mBall;
    const float DECELERATION = 1000;
    Vector2 position = Vector2.Zero;
    Vector2 velocity;

  //Update method
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // TODO: Add your update logic here
            while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
            {
                GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
                if (IsPointInObject(position))
                {
                    if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Flick)
                        velocity += gesture.Delta;
                    if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Hold)
                        position = gesture.Position;
                }
            }

            // Use velocity to adjust position and decelerate
            if (velocity != Vector2.Zero)
            {
                float elapsedSeconds = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                position += velocity * elapsedSeconds;
                float newMagnitude = velocity.Length() - DECELERATION * elapsedSeconds;
                velocity.Normalize();
                velocity *= Math.Max(0, newMagnitude);
            }
            UpdateSprite(gameTime, ref position, ref velocity);
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }



//method to detect whether the touched point lies inside the object ball
  public bool IsPointInObject(Vector2 positionVector)
        {
            Rectangle bbx = new Rectangle((int)position.X , (int)position.Y, (int)cat.Width, (int)cat.Height);
            return bbx.Contains((int)(positionVector.X), (int)(positionVector.Y));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set a canvas on TouchPanel and set and lock this canvas for gesture movements from player. You'll have to set canvas block smaller from Panel, where you want to see touch effect.

Comment: sorry but could you find me a working demo for this?